# How would I use Travis to automatically update a Github repo with result of build?

Tags: github, travis-ci

My real need is somewhat more complicated, but I think this simplification captures the essence:

What I would like to do is, on every GitHub check-in, if the rest of the Travis build succeeds, to create an artifact from the code (a minified version of the JavaScript that makes up the main source code.)  Then of course, I want Travis to check that back into GitHub.

I haven't tried this yet, because I see an immediate problem: an infinite loop.  If Travis checks this into GitHub, then of course Travis would notice another check-in and run another build, create another artifact...

How could I best avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Travis will ignore all commits whose message contains `[ci skip]`, so when you commit the minified scripts from travis make sure that is part of the message. If you need any more help I'd be happy to give some code examples.

Comment: Ah, perfect.  I _figured_ others would have had this issue, but I hadn't seen that bit anywhere.  Thank you!