# How to prevent travis build loop when deploying to master

Tags: git, github, deployment, r-markdown, travis-ci

I'm new to travis and i'm trying to use it to knitt a heavy Rmarkdown document and deploy it in my repository when it's done.

I use the following travis.yml that I scavenged around the web so I am not entirely sure about the functionning of the `deploy` options.

```
language: r
pandoc_version: 2.7.3
cache: packages
script:
 - Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('Mydoc.Rmd','bookdown::word_document2', quiet = TRUE)"
 - Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('Mydoc.Rmd','bookdown::html_document2', quiet = TRUE)"
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  keep_history: true
  target_branch: master
```

Before I added the `target_branch` options, travis was creating a new branch in my repo `gh-pages` to deploy my docs. I found it unconvienient and forced the deployement on the master but now travis builds are successfully but looping indefinitely.

This seems legitimate as it deploys my build to my repository's master branch and is
meant to build when there is a change in this branch but is there a way to prevent travis to work when the changes are from travis?

I'm sorry if my problem is basic and my question unclear but I would love to avoid useless resources usage.
Thanks for your help and have a nice day!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btravis-ci%5D+loop

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I understand that these questions are indeed related but i can't find the solution following the link. As I said i'm not very familiar with travis. Do you have a practical (code example?) solution? Again, thank you very much!

Comment: This is the linked duplicate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24583664/7976758; [Example commit:](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/commit/a753630d29f39c41247d48a373ed1cf7c77b17f1). It has `[skip ci]` for a different reason (no changes in code, only in docs) but the message is the same.